# How to add more than one currency in grid table in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

In my kendo grid, I have two currency column one is rupees and one's USD I want both currency symbol in my Grid as of now am getting only dollar symbol with a help of format in kendo grid can anyone help me get out this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The If you add a create a client template for your column then you can use a javascript function to format the value, overriding the kendo.cultures.currency.

Comment: Do you need to edit them as well? And do you need to edit both or only one of them?